# JavaFX performance: guidelines for choosing of control types

Tags: java, performance, javafx

Are there any performance differences between element types which in a certain aspect might have the same function? When I have say 20 items in a listView compared to a choiceBox, it seems the GUI is responding slower in the case of the choiceBox. Are there any performane guidelines, pertaining to use of javaFX controls in general, when speed is critical?